# Can I add terraform dynamic block , if there is already a configuration defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to add S3 lifecycle rule for an S3 bucket, expiring objects under certain prefixes.

There is already a rule defined in the terraform file

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "build_bucket" {
  bucket = "aws-s3-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  lifecycle_rule {
    enabled = true
    prefix  = "app1/beta/plist/"

    expiration {
      days = 1
    }
  }
}
```

There is a requirement to delete the builds inside `app1/alpha/ , app1/beta/ ... app4/alpha/ , app4/beta/` after 180 days.

**Can I add a dynamic block like this, will it work ?**

```
variable "lifecycle_rules" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["app1/beta/","app1/alpha/","app2/beta/","app2/alpha/","app3/beta/","app3/alpha/","app4/beta/","app4/alpha/"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "build_bucket" {
  bucket = "aws-s3-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  lifecycle_rule {
    enabled = true
    prefix  = "app1/beta/plist/"

    expiration {
      days = 1
    }
  }

  dynamic "lifecycle_rule" {
    for_each = var.lifecycle_rules
    iterator = rule
    content {
      enabled = true
      prefix  = rule.value

      expiration {
        days = 180
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the above terraform code and and it does work

[image]